# Lotus Notes: Print/write variant() to freefile() .csv

Tags: lotus-notes, notesview

I just want to ask how to print a variant() --> "tmpArray" to .csv? Because in the code that I have right now, it's only accessing the first value in the array. I want to access all the values in the array and print it in .csv file. Below is my code. Would appreciate any suggestions/help. Thanks.

For example I have 3 documents same value.

```html
tmpArray3(0) = 2,999
tmpArray3(1) = 4,999
tmpArray4(0) = 1,000
tmpArray4(1) = 5,903
```

The one which is being printed for the 1st document is: 2,999 and 1,000.
The one which is being printed for the 2nd document is: 2,999 and 1,000.
The one which is being printed for the 3rd document is: 2,999 and 1,000.

It's not proceeding to the second value in the variant array.

```html
 Do While doccount1 < 11 AND Not v2entry Is Nothing

            ReDim Preserve tmpArray3(tmpcount3)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray4(tmpcount4)

            tmpArray3(tmpcount3) = v2entry.ColumnValues(3)
            tmpArray4(tmpcount4) = v2entry.ColumnValues(4)
           

            doccount1 = doccount1 + 1

            tmpcount3=tmpcount3 + 1
            tmpcount4=tmpcount4 + 1
         

            Print #datafileNum%,(tmpArray3(0) & ";" & tmpArray4(0))
            Set v2entry = vc.GetNextEntry(v2entry)

        Loop
    Next
    Close datafileNum%
    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that in your Print statement you are accessing the first index (i.e. index 0) of the array for tmpArray3 and tmpArray4. You need to put a variable in there instead.

For example:

```html
 Do While doccount1 < 11 AND Not v2entry Is Nothing

            ReDim Preserve tmpArray3(tmpcount3)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray4(tmpcount4)

            tmpArray3(tmpcount3) = v2entry.ColumnValues(3)
            tmpArray4(tmpcount4) = v2entry.ColumnValues(4)
           

            doccount1 = doccount1 + 1
                       

            Print #datafileNum%,(tmpArray3(tmpcount3) & ";" & tmpArray4(tmpcount4))
            Set v2entry = vc.GetNextEntry(v2entry)

            tmpcount3=tmpcount3 + 1
            tmpcount4=tmpcount4 + 1

        Loop
    Next
    Close datafileNum%
    Exit Sub
```

However, you are also always retreiving index 3 and 4 from the v2entry.ColumnValues(). I assume you want to replace the 3 and 4 with a variable as well

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.